# Can't Click Top Button if Overlap Buttons in Android

Tags: android, button, onclick, imageview, onclicklistener

I am building a layout that has a button that matches the size of its parent which when clicked does function A. However, I want there to be a secondary button which when clicked does function B that sits on top of it. I've defined a relative layout with the following:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/clickButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@null" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/autoplay"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/autoplay_width"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding_normal"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/autoplay_no" />
```

I set an `onClickListener` in MainActivity for the ImageView. I know it works because if I adjust the size of buttons so they're next to each other, they both work. However, if I stack them like I did above, the ImageView's `onClickListener` never fires. I would have thought its clicks would take precedence because it's rendered last, but it doesn't seem to. I've tried switching the order, but it doesn't help. How can I stack them so that clickButton is clickable everywhere except the small square that the ImageView takes up, and the ImageView is clickable there?

Comment: Have you tried using an ImageButton?

Comment: Yes, I tried an ImageButton. It made no difference.

Comment: And you are using a `View.OnClickListener` right?

Comment: Correct, I am using a `View.OnClickListener`.